# PhonegapPluginPush - getting "OK" as push data

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugin-push

We're trying to get data from a push when the application is killed.

Here a stack info:

```
Android: 8
device: Xiaomi Redmi 5
cordova: 7.1.0
cordova-android: 6.4.0
phonegap-plugin-push: 2.1.2
```

**Registration and Handlers Set**

user registers **FCM** token and exec. the following code. Finally

```
push.on('notification', (data) => { 
   .... statement_1
    callbackA(data); 
})

push.subscribe('notification', (data) => { 
   .... statement_2
   // This statement is called only if 
   //   app is closed and the user taps 
   //   onto notification in the shade 
})
```

We are registering and subscribing to on the same 'notification' event due to a problem with Android / App Closed. ( Normally, 'notification' event is not triggered if user tap on the notification when the app is killed -- see https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2859 )

**server push request example**

```
{
  "registration_ids" : [ "...." ],
  "priority" : 5,
  "data" : {
    "title" : "Push with URL",
    "message" : "Questo invece è un esempio di push con un URL ",
    "purpose" : "NEWS",
    "id" : "2",
    "notId" : 5,
    "url" : "https://www.ciao.it/",
    "actions":[
         {
            "title":"Accept",
            "callback":"show",
            "foreground":true
         }
      ]
  }
}
```

Problem is that now, the event is triggered correctly, but **plugin pass ad data 'OK' string** instead push data for both statements (1-2).

What's wrong?

(FYI: Normal scenarios [background, foreground] are working correctly).

Answer (score 0):

We solve considering the ADB logcat.

In the app re-open process, it's clear that the listener was registered after the plugin's intent is processed.

So, as the first rows of the main ".run" module statement, we put the following code

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {}
      });
      push.on("notification", function(data) {
        $$PushManager.init(data);
      });
    }
  });
```

With the above rows, we are able to treat push with the service in charge of that.

Simon